# what does it mean: 'std::ios_base& (*f)(std::ios_base&))'

Tags: c++

I was looking for the best way to convert string to int and I came across a function I don't understand:

```
template <class T>
bool from_string(T& t, 
                 const std::string& s, 
                 std::ios_base& (*f)(std::ios_base&))
{
  std::istringstream iss(s);
  return !(iss >> f >> t).fail();
}
```

I know what template is, I don't know what it means:

```
std::ios_base& (*f)(std::ios_base&)
```

Is a new pointer being created here, why are there 2 expressions enclosed in parenthesis next to each other?

Comment: Best way is to use
std::strtol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a pointer to a function which takes a `std::ios_base&` as the
argument, and returns an `std::ios_base&`.

In fact, it's one form of a manipulator which doesn't take any
arguments. The `<<` overload for this type simply calls the function;
the function then does whatever it likes on the stream, returning it.
Your function can thus be called with something like:

```
from_string( anInt, "0A", &std::hex );
```

Comment: +1 for recognizing the ostream manipulators signatures. Decrypting the function signature is easy, but no other seemed to understand the particular semantics :)

Comment: @MatthieuM: it's almost an offense to "+1" James for recognizing an iostream manipulator. :-) What's scary is that three other persons who answered did not recognize it. I think one should know about at least the general way the things that one uses, work. Cheers,

Comment: And btw, can you tell me something, if this functions returns bool value, why does the actual conversion take place? It says 'return !(iss >> f >> t).fail()' at the end. I read here (although I am aware some guys saying that this site is 'ridden with errors') http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/fail/ that 'fail' function returns only true or false, it doesn't execute any command if the statement that is being checked is true or something like that. ADDED: Hmm, maybe this conversion is performed beforehand, and since arguments are passed by reference, they can be used later

Comment: `(iss >> f >> t)` has type `istream&` (since that's what the `>>` returns.  This is what `fail()` is called on, and `fail()` returns a `bool`.  I'd probably have written it in two lines: `iss >> f >> t; return iss;` (using the implicit conversion of an `istream` to a type which implicitly converts to `bool`.  Just `return iss >> f >> t;` would also work.  (And while I'm at it, I'd check for `f == NULL` first, and not try to output it if it was.)

Answer (score 2):

That is a declaration of a pointer `f` to a function that is taking `std::ios_base&` and returning `std::ios_base&`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a function pointer named `f` that returns a `std::ios_base&` and accepts `std::ios_base&` as its single argument.